Session partitioning in multiple windows losing sessions after closing the app - ElectronJS
I have an electronJS app where I am allowing users to load multiple messaging services at once. The app also lets you have multiple tabs with the same messaging service for example messenger. My goal is to make it so that when you open 2 tabs both with messenger, that both tabs have their unique session so you can be logged in with different accounts in those 2 tabs.
The solution I found was to use
webPreferences: {
     partition: `persist:${chat.id}`
},

This sort of works. It lets me load two messengers and login separately. The problem is that when I close my electron app, both sessions get lost and both windows redirect me to messenger login page. This is my full code for creating chat windows:
function createChatWindow(chat, mainWindow) {
const [mainWindowX, mainWindowY] = mainWindow.getPosition();
const chatWindowX = mainWindowX + 8;
const chatWindowY = mainWindowY + headerHeight;

let chatWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    parent: mainWindow,
    width: mainWindow.getSize()[0] - 15,
    height: mainWindow.getSize()[1] - headerHeight,
    x: chatWindowX,
    y: chatWindowY,
    webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
        partition: `persist:${chat.id}`
    },
    frame: false,
    backgroundColor: '#00000000',
    movable: false,
    hasShadow: false,
    transparent: true,
    resizable: false,
    skipTaskbar: true
});

chatWindow.loadURL(chat.messaging_service.url);

P.S. the chat.id is unique for every window and the same chat.id is used when I restart the app, so the pertition name should be the same, but for some reason sessions get lost anyways.
